# How to add a forward slash to the end of wordpress home?

Tags: core, site-url

I have a wordpress site - domain.com/tickets

domain.com redirects to another site - this will be fixed soon but will redirect for a few more months.

So when I go into WP settings I put in domain.com/tickets/ for my site but it drops the last forward slash every time.

The "breaks" the site during logout, login, registration because domain.com/tickets gets redirected because it isn't one full level up.  The server is IIS 7.5 W2008 R2.

Comment: This sounds like something you would want to do with `.htaccess`

Comment: this is nothing to do with htaccess

Comment: Yes... Especially since I mentioned IIS.

Answer (score 1):

It depands on property `use_trailing_slashes` of WP_Rewrite object, which is set based on your `permalinks_structure`.

Please open Settings -> Permalinks. If your Custom Structure ends with `/` all urls will be forsed to use slash, if no - no.

Comment: Login and logout still take me to domain.com/tickets even after making the permalink changes.  I see the changes everywhere else so they took fine.